# How can I use mongodb $lookup and $unionWith to get documnets from two collections

Tags: mongodb

1st collection

```
stocks = [
{"userId" : 1, "groupId": 1, "stockId": 1},
{"userId": 2, "groupId": 1, "stockId": 2},
{"userId": 3, "groupId": 4, "stockId": 3}
]
```

2nd collection:

```
items = [
{"userid": 1, "groupId": 1, "itemId": 1},
{"userid": 1, "groupId": 3, "itemId": 2},
{"userid": 1, "groupId": 4, "itemId": 3}
]
```

I have a collection user, from which i get the userid, here i have filtered to get userid as  1, I have tried the below lookup, i am getting all data for userid, but when I add condition to exclude group, its not working. can someone help or suggest where i am doing wrong?

```
{
  from: "stocks",
  localField: "user.id",
  foreignField: "userId",
  let: {group_id: "$groupId", user_id: "$userId" },
  pipeline: [{ "$unionWith": { coll: "items", pipeline: [{$match: {$userid: "$$user_id", "$groupId": { $nin: ["$$group_id"]}}}]}}],
  as: "stock_items"
}
```

I need list of data where userId and groupId should not be same, i need all the data from stocks and items excluding item[0], since both have same user id and group id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure that I understand what you are asking for. I'm also confused by the sample aggregation that has been provided because fields like `"user.id"` doesn't exist in the sample documents. But at the end you specifically mention:

> i need all the data from stocks and items excluding item[0], since both have same user id and group id

Based on that, this answer assumes that you are looking to find all documents in both collections where the value of the `groupId` field is different than the value of the `userId` field. If that is correct, then the following query should work:

```
db.stocks.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $ne: [
          "$groupId",
          "$userId"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unionWith": {
      "coll": "items",
      "pipeline": [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $ne: [
                "$groupId",
                "$userId"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground demonstration here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/u1R0vGIwyKA).

The way this operates is by using [the `$ne` aggregation operator](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ne/) to compare the two fields in the document. We need to use the `$expr` operator to do this comparison as shown [here in the documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.2/reference/operator/query/expr/#compare-two-fields-from-a-single-document).

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I found out the let won't work here as expected and $nin can't be used in aggregate function. I need to perform a $nin similar operation.

Comment: The $ne is giving all the data, it is not excluding the data.

Comment: I had a typo and was accidentally using `$stockId` instead of `$userId`. I've corrected that in the answer as well as the [playground demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/u1R0vGIwyKA). Note that only 5 of the 6 sample documents are returned, the first document in the `items` collection (with `_id: 1`) correctly does **not** get returned.